# Consuming React useContext in a class based component in TypeSCript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am using our cartContext in a functional component like this:

```
import { CartContext } from '../../contexts/CartContext';

function staticCart(){
    const { increase, decrease, removeProduct } = useContext(CartContext);
    const { total, cartItems, shipping, netTotal, vat, finalTotal } = useContext(CartContext);
    return (
         <React.Fragment>Logic to use the complex cart contexts</React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And this working fine as expected. And we have a class-based component, which looks like this:

```
import- statements

class StaticCart extends COmponent<RouteComponentProps<any>, State> {
    protected datatypes
    
    constructor(props: any) {
        ...
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                ...
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the above same method(as in functional components) to the class Components.

I have tried:

- Using as static type as mentioned here: https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/#class-component
- Place contexts in an external function based file, getting some other error
- Placing the contexts inside Render
  But nothing seems to work. I am highly confused of the docs present, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a context in React will give 2 things one is the `Provider` and `Consumer` . The `Provider` remains the same for both the class and functional components.

For functional components we can replace the `Consumer` with the `useContext`. But for class components you need to use `Consumer`

```
<CartContext.Consumer>
{(value) => { return ( .... )}}
</CartContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this approach,

```
import- statements

class StaticCart extends COmponent<RouteComponentProps<any>, State> {
    protected datatypes
    
    static contextType = CartCOntext;
    constructor(props: any) {
        ...
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        const { increase, decrease, removeProduct } = useContext(CartContext);
const { total, cartItems, shipping, netTotal, vat, finalTotal } = useContext(CartContext);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                ...
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Which has worked for me.